# How to stop Delegate Methods to Run before Data gets loaded from JSON?

Tags: ios, uitableview, afnetworking

I am using AFNetworking GET method in ViewDidLoad. My UITableView delegate methods runs before data is loaded in Arrays. I am getting error of NSArray beyond bounds .

Please help me through it . Its my first time o JSON .

I searched Stackoverflow and google .But didn't got proper answer.

Comment: Loading data in success block of AFNetworking GET Method.

Comment: You should check count of array before accessing element with hard coded index. It doesn't matter if tableview delegate gets called before loading data. Tableview asks for data on view appear. You can reload table again once you have data from server.

Comment: plz provide method code for numberOfRowsInSection...

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't be refreshing your table view before the download completes if you don't want it pulling in data from blank arrays.

You should be refreshing your data in the success block of your `AFNetworking` call.

```
[connectionMgr GET:@"yourURL" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { //Note that 204 is considered a success message

        //Reload your table view
        [self.tableView reloadData];

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) { //Note that this is called even if the download is cancelled manually

        //Failure
}];
```

**EDIT**

Since you're using a `UITableViewController`, you should put a check in your `numberOfRowsInSection` to see if the array is `nil` or if it contains `0` objects. Then it won't try to generate any cells.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    if (array == nil || array.count < 1) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return array.count; //Or whatever you're using
    }
}
```

I'm assuming that you aren't using `array.count` for the number of cells, otherwise you probably wouldn't be having this issue.

Comment: I am refreshing the table in Success block . But still it gets the null arrays before . Anyway to stop the methods to initiate before the data loads in :( ?

Comment: What's calling the method? Are you using a `UITableViewController`?

Comment: Yeah i am using UItableviewcontroller

Comment: In your init method, initialize the array to a blank array.

Comment: Yeah, if you do what @AdamPro13 said, you don't need the `if` in the above example, you can just return `array.count`.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest having an NSArray property that will contain the data you are going to put in the table view. `numberOfRowsForSection:` return the count of the array. In your success block, set the array equal to the data you have returned & call `reloadData`. This way your table view will try creating 0 cells when there's no data & as many as you need after you have received the data.

Comment: I am reloading the data in Success block .That block works on background . So the code jumps to the TableViewdelegate methods

Comment: I know. If I understand correctly, you don't want the table view to show anything until the data has returned, correct?